# Blogger - How to Percent Encode an URL / Escape It to Use as Query Param?

Tags: facebook, twitter, blogger, blogspot

In blogspot template engine how do you escape the post URL to use it as a query param so you can use it in facebook / twitter / whatever buttons and iframes?

Problem: I have an iframe with a src that takes an URL.

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=MY_URL_GOES_HERE">
```

So say my post URL is `http://example.blogspot.com/1999/01/first.html`. I need to convert `:/.` to percent encoded characters, and also `?&%` etc. Otherwise I get this:

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http://example.blogspot.com/1999/01/first.html">
```

And that just looks like it's going to break someday. How can I escape the URL in blogger?

Answer (score 3):

The way to do it is pretty simple and all it takes is wasting a couple of hours searching every corner of the internet for some semblance of documentation on blogspot's template engine and reading through a bunch of StackOverflow's answer that just dismiss the question with "use shareurl instead."

Anyway. Every string in blogspot templates has a `.escaped` field that is the string escaped. That is it. You just anyurl.escaped and it works. It can be `data:post.url.escaped` or `data:post.url.canonical.escaped` or whatever.

```
<iframe
  expr:src="&quot;https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=&quot;
    + data:post.url.canonical.escaped + &quot;width=173&amp;layout=button_count&amp;action=like&amp;size=small&amp;show_faces=false&amp;share=true&amp;height=46&amp;appId=YOUR_APP_ID_HERE&quot;" width="173"
height="46" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Other elusive string attributes can be found in this extremely fishy blog: http://template-data.blogspot.com.br/2016/04/title_58.html

You'd think google would have this info somewhere easy to find but all they got are blogger HTTP API docs? What?